# Remove duplicate rows in big file

Tags: java, bloom-filter

How do I remove duplicate rows of string while reading a .fastq(text) file using Java? Currently work with next-generation sequencing (ngs) and need to remove duplicate readings from file sequenced (big data). I'm trying with [Counting Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) and [Cuckoo filter](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf) in java but still can not succeed.

Comment: How exactly are you not succeeding? Do you not find duplicates or is is to slow or does it crash or...?

Answer (score 0):

Bloom filters are `O(1)` lookup so you can't get much faster than that.

The other bottleneck for any kind of filter is the data read speed. Are you reading the file as fast as possible?

If it's just a bloom filter implementation you are looking for I've used the [Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.html) one successfully.

Please give us more details of your problems, then we should be able to help more.